# Iframe allow=autoplay not workinf on firefox

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, soundcloud

I'm working with soundcloud embed iframe code. There is option from soundcloud to autoplay audio and it's defined as `&auto_play=true` url parameter in iframe `src` attribute.

But there is other iframe attribute `allow="autoplay 'none'"` which won't allow iframe to play that audio and it's not working in firefox.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide#Example_Disabling_autoplay

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Browser_compatibility

HTML:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/148714961&color=%23ea00ff&auto_play=true&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
```

https://codepen.io/balancana/pen/WPKjoE

The problem is that I want to stop soundcloud iframe audio file to play 
no matter what's `auto_play` url parameter.

Comment: Just remove the `allow` attribute. By default it's disabled by its absence.

Comment: @zer00ne hmm but it will still autoplay in firefox https://codepen.io/balancana/pen/OdwjwP Is there any workaround for Firefox?

Comment: ATM this [lame plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/soundcloud-autoplay/) is the solution for individual users but for developers there [ain't no such thang](https://community.soundcloud.com/desktop-230066/disable-autoplay-7355001)

Answer (score -2):

You have to allow fire fox to have permission to autoplay audio
[click this link to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TGA6.png)

Comment: This only works for one consumer - means "you", not for a developer trying to embed content for "all" consumers ;-)